# How to get the names of all attributes in an XML file using R's xml2 package

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I'm trying to get the names of all attributes in an XML file using R's xml2 package.

I can get the names of attributes at a single level using the `xml_attrs()` function, but can't figure out how to get the attributes at all levels. See example below.

Any help much appreciated.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

# Make up some data
dat <- read_xml(
  "<LEVEL1 attr_lvl1='a'>
    <LEVEL2 attr_lvl2='b'>
    </LEVEL2>
    <LEVEL2 attr_lvl2='c'>
    </LEVEL2>  
  </LEVEL1>"  
)

# I know how to get the attributes for each level...
names(xml_attrs(dat)) #"attr_lvl1"
names(xml_attrs(xml_child(dat, 'LEVEL2'))) #"attr_lvl2"

# Want code which returns the names of attributes across 
# *all* levels, i.e. should return "attr_lvl1", "attr_lvl2"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over all nodes, get the attribute names, and then create a vector of the unique values. You can do that with

```
dat %>% 
  xml_find_all("//*") %>% 
  purrr::map(~names(xml_attrs(.))) %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  unique()
# [1] "attr_lvl1" "attr_lvl2"
```

There's really no way to know what all the attributes could be without iterating all the nodes (unless your XML has some sort of schema you could query).

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, this is very helpful. I've noticed however that your code returns the error "Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0" if a node has no attribute (e.g., by removing "attr_lvl1='a'" from my example data. Is it possible to extend the code to work if some nodes have no attributes? Thanks again

Comment: @jruf003 Sure. I updated with code that will work with missing attributes.